# How can I ensure domain network share are always discovered on a Mac?

Tags: macos, networking, mac, windows-domain, network-discovery

My office network is a domain network. We have a couple mac (Yosemite) users in the network who need access to shared folders. They have intermittent access. Sometimes the network is discovered on their mac's startup, sometimes it is not. The only solution they have found is to reboot their machine until the network appears in the Finder.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's too easy you can renew the DHCP, in Macs
in Terminal just write this :

```
sudo ifconfig en1 down
sudo ifconfig en1 up
```

For the wired interface, replace en1 with en0.

instead of that this can also be achieved with the following two commands :

```
sudo ipconfig set en0 BOOTP
sudo ipconfig set en0 DHCP
```

You can alias the two together in your bash profile:

```
alias renew="sudo ipconfig set en0 BOOTP && sudo ipconfig set en0 DHCP"
```

So then you just have one command called `renew` that will release and renew your DHCP.

after that again try to discover you domain !

Comment: Sorry - somehow never saw your answer, but it is correct. Marked as answered.